# Is there any difference between accessing a subject directly on a class or using a getter

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Lets say I have a service that exposes a subject:

```js
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class StateService {
  private mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("test");
  mySubject$ = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  constructor() {}

  updateSubject(value: string) {
    this.mySubject.next(value);
  }

  get mySubject2$() {
    return this.mySubject.asObservable();
  }
}
```

In my component:

```js
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { StateService } from "./state.service";

@Component({
  //...
})
export class AppComponent {
  name = this.state.mySubject$;
  name2 = this.state.mySubject2$;

  constructor(private state: StateService) {}
}
```

Are there any differences apart from stylistic in terms of using an accessor to return the subject or accessing it directly via a property on the class?

Comment: people tent to overuse accessor where there is no requirement. I dont see any point here to use getter. I use getter only when there is a complex nested object and I want to access inner value frequently.

Comment: and for me it is exact case where we should use accessor as defined by the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors) `mySubject$` is not a real property of the class, just a controlled way to access to `mySubject `. But is probably a primary base opinion.

Comment: Interesting, thanks! I agree, I was once told on stackoverflow that we should always return in a method, but couldn't find a reason why

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are two differences:

1. When you invoke the `get` [accessor](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#accessors), it calls [`Subject#asObservable`](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/fc4829c2fe8ee48b975ef042606b82efeee92e24/src/internal/Subject.ts#L136-L146) to create a new observable for each consumer, whereas the property is a single observable. An observable can have multiple subscribers, so it's slightly less efficient to create multiple observables.
2. When you use a public property, unless you explicitly mark it [`readonly`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier), consumers can replace the observable, so that subsequent access wouldn't get the observable linked to the subject the instance is managing.

In your case, I would probably use:

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { BehaviorSubject } from "rxjs";

@Injectable()
export class StateService {
  private mySubject = new BehaviorSubject<string>("test");
  readonly mySubject$ = this.mySubject.asObservable();

  updateSubject(value: string) {
    this.mySubject.next(value);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! neverthought of the `readonly` aspect. What will be the use case for, the need for each consumer to have its own observable?

Comment: @C_Ogoo I don't think there is one, that's why I wouldn't use the accessor.

Comment: Order is important here, and `this.mySubject.asObservable()` is called before the constructor. Rarely is this an issue, but usage of a getter allows the body of the getter to execute after the constructor and it doesn't matter where in the class you define the getter. So remember that the value of `this` is pre-constructor and relative to the order. You can not do a circular `x = this.y; y = this.x;` as an example. I've run into this problem with observables, because you sometimes need pipes and want to reuse them.